# rvest web scraping is returning an empty data frame when attempting to collect product price information

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to use 'rvest' to scrape product pricing from: https://www.lowes.com/pl/Lawn-garden-hand-tools-Outdoor-tools-equipment-Outdoors/4294612737?goToProdList=true&int_cmp=LawnGardenHandTools:C:Outdoors:Merch:shop_all_copy. I am using the below code:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url <- "https://www.lowes.com/pl/Lawn-garden-hand-tools-Outdoor-tools-equipment-Outdoors/4294612737?goToProdList=true&int_cmp=LawnGardenHandTools:C:Outdoors:Merch:shop_all_copy"

html <- read_html(url)

price <- html %>%
  html_node('body') %>%
  xml_find_all("//span[contains(@class, 'h5 js-price v-spacing-mini art-pl-price')]") %>% 
  html_text() %>%
  data.frame()
```

However - this is returning an empty data frame.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: At what point do you `read_html` (or similar)?

Comment: apologies - when writing out the example above I forgot to include that stage. I have now edited the example code.

Comment: Thanks, that's a common-enough mistake in SO: not posting the real code that is actually being run on the console. It's simple and an easy mistake to make, but it makes troubleshooting a lot harder: do we assume that it's a typo and ignore it, or is that a problem that is contributing to the overall issue? When I ask questions (SO or other SE sites), I try to make it a habit to paste my code into a new empty R session and see if I forgot something; inevitably, whenever I shortcut that step, I mis-type the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rvest` can only scrape static HTML content.

Most modern commercial websites use dynamic web content generated on the fly by a JavaScript.

In order to scrape such websites, you will first need to make the site generate the HTML content you are looking for, and then you'll be able to scrape it with `rvest`.

To do so, you'll need to use a web browser emulator like [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html) or [Splash](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splashr/vignettes/intro_to_splashr.html) to allow you  to move around in the site and query data programmatically.

RSelenium needs installation of a [Docker Selenium server](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome/). This is also recommended for Splash.

At the end of this long and interesting journey, you'll have to be creative so that the Website doesn't think that it's being queried by a robot :
[image: bot Captcha]

Comment: Really appreciate the advice! I am still quite new to web scraping - and was just wondering why that would mean I am able to still scrape some things successfully? As I was able to scrape the product names using rvest?

Comment: Side note, though, that I've been reminded of several times: while the page itself might have dynamic content that `rvest` may not see, often you'll may find js-loaded links that can directly get to the raw data. For instance, in the web-browser (not R), open the dev console and look at network traffic; often you'll see secondary content loading that may allow you to use straight-`rvest` (or even just `GET`) to get what you need. (I've even found direct JSON sources, unfortunately not in this specific Lowes link.)